# Checking format of CSV using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently working on a script to check if a bunch of CSVs have an adequate format for another one to process it. I'm having trouble with some of the assertions It haves to pass. One is to have no missings, for which I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:PATH\\test.csv", sep= ',')

def check(self, file):
try:
    assert df.notna().values.any()  
except AssertionError:
    assert False, "  NaN in data"
```

It does nothing. I tried it on a CSV with NaNs and it didn't raise an error. Then, I also want it with comma separated, but they may pass me a dot and comma separated one. This is my try:

```
try:
    assert len(df.columns) != 1 
except AssertionError:      
    "Not comma separated"
```

It responds poorly, sometimes raises the flag, sometimes it doesn't.

Is there something from "assert" I didn't understand or is something else the issue?

Comment: I think it should be `.all()` instead of `.any()` in `assert df.notna().values.any()`

Comment: I tried now, but the test CSV still pass.

Comment: Are you calling the check method with right file?

Comment: Yes, it loads correctly (I'm using Spyder, It shows in the variable explorer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass df as parameter to `check()`.
Also change `.any()` to `.all()`

```
df= pd.read_csv("C:\\PATH\\test.csv", sep= ',')

def check(file):
    try:
        assert file.notna().values.all()  
    except AssertionError:
        assert False, "  NaN in data"

check(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

`pd.notna()` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.notna.html

requires you to provide dataframe as argument

Please try using notnull() as below:

```
df= pd.read_csv("C:PATH\\test.csv", sep= ',')

def check(file):
    try:
        assert file.notnull().values.any() 
    except AssertionError:
        assert False, "  NaN in data"

check(df)
```

Comment: I think `notnull()` is an alias of `notna()` : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html#pandas.DataFrame.notna